# Don't want to JSON serialize the whole list of classes

Tags: c#, json, serialization, adaptor

I've got a `IList` of Sites in my application and Site has a large amount of properties.

I'm wanting to convert this list to JSON to be used in a dropdownlist similar to this

```
    var sites = SiteRepository.FindAllSites();
    return new JsonResult() { Data = sites, JsonRequestBehavior = JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet };
```

the problem I have is that I only want to use the id and name properties of the site class. I was thinking a way round this would be to use an 'adaptor' class that would then only expose these two properties and I would then serialize that.

The problem I have is I want to make the class generic so that it can handle any list of objects. Has anybody come across a similar situation and solved it?

EDIT: I can't use the `[ScriptIgnore]` Attribute as there may be a case when I do want to serialize the whole class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can you create an anonymous class from your list of sites?

```
var sites = SiteRepository.FindAllSites().Select(x=> new { Id=x.Id, Name=x.Name});
```

Since `FindAllSites()` seems to return an `IList`, which is descended from `IEnumberable`, you should be able to use `System.Linq`'s extension methods (i.e. `Select()` ). That'll transform the `List<Site>` (with all the properties) to `IEnumerable<some_anon_class>` (with only 2 properties) which is then given to that `JsonResult` thing instead of the list of `Site`.

Comment: Good solution, but doesn't it need to be: var sites = SiteRepository.FindAllSites().Select(x => new { Id = x.Id, Name = x.Name }); ?

Answer (score 0):

If you decorate you class fields with [ScriptIgnore] (System.Web.Script.Serialization) C# will ignore them during serialization using Json in much the same way that decorating with [XmlIgnore] would for Xml serialization.

[MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute.aspx)

Comment: Sorry I should have mentioned this in the question. There may be times when I want to serialize the whole Site class to pass it back via an ajax request